# How do I obtain the version information for my Windows Service programmatically

Tags: c#, setup-project

I need to obtain the version of my Windows service programmatically and store it in a string.  Then, I'll append the version to my display name and service name in the ProjectInstaller class.  Right now I'm getting an empty string and I'm having trouble debugging my setup project.  Here's my current code:

```
        string version = null;
        try
        {
            Assembly exeAssembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
            Type attrType = typeof(AssemblyFileVersionAttribute);
            object[] attributes = exeAssembly.GetCustomAttributes(attrType, false);
            if (attributes.Length > 0)
            {
                AssemblyFileVersionAttribute verAttr = (AssemblyFileVersionAttribute)attributes[0];
                if (verAttr != null)
                {
                    version = verAttr.Version;
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        if (version == null)
        {
            version = string.empty;
        }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var version = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
return version.ToString();
```

Will return it in 1.0.0.0 form.

Or, you can use the `version.Major + "." + version.Minor` to get just the first two numbers.

Alternatively, if you want the file version...

```
var fvi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
return fvi.FileVersion;
```

Comment: This worked!  How do I preserve the leading zeros (i.e., 050000.01.01.00 is showing up as 50000.1.1.0)?

Comment: If you know how many leading zeroes are needed you can use something like `version.Major.ToString().PadLeft(10, '0') + "." + version.Minor`, etc.

Comment: Also, if this answer was helpful to you, would you mind clicking the "Up-arrow" to vote for it?  Thanks.

Comment: I did click the check mark.  When I tried to click the "Up-arrow", it stated that "Vote Up requires 15 reputation".